# Integrate $\int \frac{x^4+1}{(x^4+2)^{3/4}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

This is a question of indefinite integration.

I tried many substitutions but could not solve it.
It is to be integrated from $0$ to $1$.
$t=x^4+1$ can't be applied here.

Comment: Why the change of variables $x\mapsto x^{4}+1$ cannot be applied here?

Comment: Two things, use https://approach0.xyz/search/ to search for math questions on the internet, and also, write two times the numerator as $[x^4+2]+[x^4]$ and for the second part, write $x^4=x \cdot x^3$ and then use by parts.

Comment: Two things, use https://approach0.xyz/search/ to search for math questions on the internet, there's an aops thread that answers this, and also, write two times the numerator as $(x^4+2)+(x^4)$ and for the second part, write $x^4=x \cdot x^3$ and then use by parts.

Comment: Which substitutions have you tried? It's usually a good idea to write out exactly what you have tried so people can tell you if you're in the right track, or to adopt a different approach.

Comment: With the change of variables $x\mapsto x^{4}+1$ we don't need integration by parts.

Comment: @user1027216 what do you do with the extra x^3 that pops up...

Comment: @Aditya_math  You're right : substitution doesn't work (at least it doesn't seem to work for me), although it might seem to be the case at first glance. I'll delete the previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=x^4+1$, then $d u=4 x^3 d x=4(u-1)^{\frac{3}{4}} d x$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{x^4+1}{\left(x^4+2\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}} d x &\stackrel{\phantom{s=u^2-1}}{=}\int \frac{u}{(u+1)^{\frac{3}{4}}} \cdot \frac{d u}{4(u-1)^{\frac{3}{4}}} \\
&\stackrel{\phantom{s=u^2-1}}{=}\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{u d u}{\left(u^2-1\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}} \\
&\stackrel{s=u^2-1}{=} \frac{1}{8} \int \frac{d s}{s^{\frac{3}{4}}}\\
&\stackrel{\phantom{s=u^2-1}}{=}\frac{1}{2} s^{\frac{1}{4}}+C \\
&\stackrel{\phantom{s=u^2-1}}{=}\frac{1}{2}(u+1)^{\frac{1}{4}}(u-1)^{\frac{1}{4}}+C \\
&\stackrel{\phantom{s=u^2-1}}{=}\frac{1}{2} x\sqrt[4]{x^4+2}+C 
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: @shoteyes, thank you for your edit.

Answer (score 1):

A sneaky subtitution ...
\begin{align}
u &= x(x^4+2)^{1/4},\\
du &=\left(\frac{x^4}{(x^4+2)^{3/4}}+(x^4+2)^{1/4}\right) dx
=\frac{2(x^4+1)}{(x^4+2)^{3/4}} dx
\end{align}
so that
$$
\int \frac{x^4+1}{(x^4+2)^{3/4}}dx
= \int\frac{1}{2}\;du
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\displaystyle I =\int \frac{x^4+1}{(x^4+2)^{\frac{3}{4}}}dx=\int \frac{x^7+x^3}{(x^8+2x^4)^{\frac{3}{4}}}dx$

Put $x^8+2x^4=t$ and $\displaystyle 8(x^7+x^3)dx=dt$

So $\displaystyle I =\frac{1}{8}\int t^{-\frac{3}{4}}dt=\frac{4}{8}t^{\frac{1}{4}}+C=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt[4]{x^4+2}+C$